# Restrict Orders View in Magento Admin to Specific Statuses

Tags: magento, admin, orders

In the Magento admin, when you click "Orders", all orders are displayed based on date.  This includes completed orders, canceled orders, etc.  We have specific statuses (Processing, Pending Shipment) and we'd like for only orders in those two statuses to show by default.

If we need to see canceled orders, for example, we can use the search, select Canceled and bring them up that way.  Restricting what shows by default would help us streamline our order processing steps by limiting our view to only those orders we need to deal with.

Where should I be looking to make this change?  It feels like it should be a simple programmatic change, but I'm not certain which files to look in.

Any insights would be much appreciated.

Thanks.